# Method does not override any method from its superclass - cell for row at index path

Tags: swift, uitableview, xcode8

I've tried deleting the override and derived data, re-writing the cell for row at index path function, re-writing the cell variable structure, and no luck.  Any idea?

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return BPC.count
}

override  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BPCCell") as! BPC_TableCell
    cell.namelabel.text = BPC[indexPath.row].name
    cell.addresslabel.text = BPC[indexPath.row].address
    return cell  
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "BPCsegue" {
        if let destViewControler = segue.destinationViewController as? BPCDetails {
            let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
            destViewControler.details = BPC[indexPath.row]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output which you are seeing on the device ?

Comment: why can't you use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Are you subclassing a table view controller, or are you implementing the data source for a table view?  Your use of "override" suggests a subclass.  Is that what you are doing?

Comment: override is only necessary when subclassing UITableViewController !  check it :)

Comment: If you are using swift 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/40491818/564485

Answer (score 2):

Methods like `cell for row at index path` only use the `override` keyword if they are subclassing `UITableViewController`. If you are having problems with not being able to override a certain method, then you are most likely not subclassing the right class.

Comment: I have a table controller and usually I never have this superclass error.  However, when I delete the override, I am left with this error. /Users/Jon/Desktop/The489/The489/BPC Table.swift:101:10: Method 'tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)' with Objective-C selector 'tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' conflicts with method 'tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)' from superclass 'UITableViewController' with the same Objective-C selector