# didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working, Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Can anyone see why in the world didSelectRowAtIndexPath would not be called?  I have triple checked by `delegate` both in the code and in storyboard.

```
class AddCard: UIViewController,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let tableItems = ["Background Color","Background Image","Font Style","Font Color"]
let cellID = "cell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setBackgroundColor (_ color: UIColor) {
    cardView.backgroundColor = color
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableItems.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath as IndexPath)

    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.textLabel?.text = tableItems[row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    print(indexPath.row)
    let row = indexPath.row
    switch(row){
    case 0:
        let popoverVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "colorPickerVC") as! ColorPickerViewController
        popoverVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        popoverVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 284, height: 446)
        if let popoverController = popoverVC.popoverPresentationController {
            popoverController.sourceView = self.view
            popoverController.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 85, height: 30)
            popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .any
            popoverController.delegate = self
            popoverVC.delegate = self
        }
        present(popoverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
    default: break

    }
}

}
```

Comment: You didn't update the signature of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to the Swift 3 one. From the doc: `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, notice the `_` the `didSelectRowAt` vs `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, like the other one you updated, but not this one. Remove the line and let XCode do the autocompletion. Else, you can just replace it with the one from the doc.

Comment: Killed it!  Thanks man.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Swift 3 modified the signature of the method (a lot of methods too, new "rules"/style)

Replace:
`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)` with 
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Notice the `_`, the `didSelectRowAt` vs `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, like the other ones you updated (which adapted also the same "style"), but not this one.

Remove the line and let XCode do the autocompletion. Else, you can just replace it with the one from the doc.

Comment: Thanks! And why on earth.... is it that when they decide to rename everything in each new version of swift, that the xcode editor does not suggest the new names when you type in a deprecated name. I'm just learning xcode and swift, and I am chocked how bad a developer experience this is.