# Image View image not changing after selecting new from library

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

First off I want to say that I'm by no means an experienced Swift programmer, so if I am missing anything for someone to help me debug my issue - then I'm sorry about that. Just drop a comment and I'll add whatever is necessary to help you help me.

I'm following Apple's guide on how to develop iOS apps with Swift (as seen [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1http://)).

But for some reason I'm getting this warning:

> Instance method 'imagePickerController(picker:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol 'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'

I've attempted to suppress the issue by both using @nonobjc and setting it to private. The problem is that the new image isn't taking the old image's place. Instead it gives me this error in the output:

> [Generic] Creating an image format with an unkown type is an error.

This is the code that concerns my tapGesture and the imagePicking:

```
// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

     func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage

        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func selectTapGestureFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Hide the keyboard
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // UIImagePickerController allows users to pick media from their photo library!

        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken

        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

If my question isn't clear enough **I need help figuring out why the image in my app isn't changing** - even though I've followed the guide. I've already noticed some issues that I assume has to do with Xcode having been updated, but not the guide.

It might be worth mentioning that I have already set the info.plist to allow me to access all the necessary security privileges.

I'm running iOS 10.1 and Xcode 8.1

Found a similar issue that together with @Larme's comment helped me solve it:

[Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3/40492091#40492091)

Comment: `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])` is not the Swift 3 correct method. As said by the compiler, it should be `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])` (the method signature changed with Swift 3). If you put a breakpoint, or logs in it, you should see that's it's not called.

Comment: @Larme Good god... I was too focused on the potential fixes to read the warning, I suppose. There has been 3-4 of similar warnings throughout the guide, so you'd think I'd know of these issues by now... :/
If you answer, I'll accept. Hopefully this will help other people too

Comment: It's the same situation I explained there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3/40492091#40492091 The methods are not the same, but the explanation is still valid. Just be careful of what say the warnings, and when you read about Swift if it's Swift 1, 2, 2.2, or 3, and you may do some little adjustments.

Comment: Curious that I didn't see that question when I googled as it does cover the exact same issue I'm facing... 
Anyways, I'd be more than happy to accept your answer when you post it.

In the meantime I'll add a reference to the question that you mentioned in your comment in case someone hits this question before finding the other!

Comment: I marked the question as duplicate. In my opinion, it's the same issue. You can chose to mark yours as such, your question will be still visible anyway, but pointing to the duplicate one too.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the help, man! Silly mistake from my side! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, Please check and sure that you have connect all the necessary outlets.