# Swift 3: Can't connect to peripheral via BLE

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm new to working with BLE, currently trying to make a simple application which would connect to my custom BLE device. I am able to discover the BLE device, but for some reason i can't connect to it.
I tried to check it with 'Light Blue', it shows my device as connectable and seems to work fine. But in my app after i discover the device, CB manager tries to connect to it and seems to 'freeze'? Function 'didConnect peripheral' is never triggered, and state of peripheral is forever 'connecting'.

How can i identify the problem? Is there any options i can include in connection method, or somehow track the connection process?

I would appreciate any advice where to search for problems.

Working in XCode 8.2.1, using Swift 3. iOS 10.2.1 installed on the testing phone

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class InfoPageViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

var manager:CBCentralManager!
var peripheral:CBPeripheral!

let BEAN_NAME = "MyDevice"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {

    let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary)
        .object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
        as? NSString

    if device?.contains(BEAN_NAME) == true {
        self.manager.stopScan()

        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral.delegate = self

        manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)

        print("discovered \(BEAN_NAME)")

    }
}

func centralManager(
    central: CBCentralManager,
    didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("connected to \(BEAN_NAME)")

    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure: I assume somewhere else you're calling `scanForPeripherals` (seems obvious since you're saying `didDiscover` is called, but it's not in the above code). Can you confirm that LightBlue can connect to the peripheral? (If you tap on it in the list, it should connect and show you the advertising data and services.) Note that once you've connected in LightBlue, you likely will not discover the device any more in your app until you disconnect in LightBlue. (And of course: just how "custom" is this device? Do you know it can actually connect? Do you have a dev kit for it?)

Comment: Yes, i call `scanForPeripherals` as part of `centralManagerDidUpdateState`, that seems to work. Didn't include it in code above, since it didn't seem to have relation to the problem. And in LightBlue i can connect to it, can see advertising data, services. I don't have a dev kit for that device, but it can be connected to another application on android (so it's connectable), but i can't understand why not the iOS.

Comment: `optional func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)` is the real declaration/signature of the method. You are missing a "_". That could be why it's not called. Internally, it's seems to be optional, it should test before "Does my delegate respond to `centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)`, and returns false.

Comment: Great catch @Larme. If that fixes it, you should definitely post as an answer. As a note: Xcode is pretty good at autocompleting delegate method signatures if you start typing "centralManager". Makes sure you get get them right (or you can cut/paste out of the headers or the docs). They're long and hard to type correctly.

Comment: just one little ''_''... oh man, i love you. thank you, that really was the issue! fixed that, func is called and device is connected now.

Comment: @RobNapier I got used to it even if I don't speak Swift, because of the passage from Swift 2.2 to Swift 3 that causes too many questions (and noise) on SO (like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {}
--------------------^
```

Versus:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)
--------------------^
```

The signature of the method is not the correct one, you are missing the `_`.

Method signatures are important.
We can assume, since theses delegate methods are optional, that internally, the Apple code asks itself:
Does my delegate have the method `func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral)` implemented (`respondsToSelector:`)? In your case, not, because it's not the same, and then yours is not called.

You copy/paste the one from the doc or remove it and let XCode do its autocompletion thing.