# Why is UICollectionView insetForSectionsAtIndex not being called?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I'm looking to use the following function but unfortunately it's not being called.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let cellCount = Double(collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section))
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section))
        {
            let cellWidth = Double(cell.frame.size.width)
            let totalCellWidth = cellWidth * cellCount
            let cellSpacing = Double(collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing)
            let totalSpacingWidth = cellSpacing * (cellCount - 1)

            let leftInset = (collectionView.frame.width - CGFloat(totalCellWidth + totalSpacingWidth)) / 2
            let rightInset = leftInset

            return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, leftInset, 0, rightInset)
        }

    return collectionView.layoutMargins
}
```

I'm getting the following console errors but my cell is smaller than my collectionView and I've set the section insets and layout margins to 0.

> 2017-03-30 11:25:14.624 Prep[92400:1862856] The behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because:
>   2017-03-30 11:25:14.624 Prep[92400:1862856] the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.
>   2017-03-30 11:25:14.624 Prep[92400:1862856] The relevant UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is , and it is attached to ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 68.5}> collection view layout: .
>   2017-03-30 11:25:14.625 Prep[92400:1862856] Make a symbolic breakpoint at UICollectionViewFlowLayoutBreakForInvalidSizes to catch this in the debugger.
>    cell height --> 42.0

[image]

Protocols

```
class OverviewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
@IBOutlet weak var vipCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var hostedMeetingsArray: [String]?
var vipArray: [Attendee]?

class OverviewViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
@IBOutlet weak var vipCollectionView: UICollectionView!

var hostedMeetingsArray: [String]?
var vipArray: [Attendee]?
```

[image]

Comment: Try to give the collection view a constant height and test if it is working. Maybe the height constraint makes the problem.

Comment: @Kingalione This gets rid of the console errors (I was using a proportional height constraint) but the function is still not called.

Comment: Did you implemented the correct delegate?

Comment: @Kingalione I've updated the question with the protocols used. I used `UICollectionViewDelegate`, `UICollectionViewDataSource`, and `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. The last of these I have declared at the top of the class and nothing more.

Comment: yes, its the correct protocol. So is cellForItemAt and numberOfItemsInSection is getting called?

Comment: @Kingalione Yes, these functions work fine as well. It just appears to be the `insetForSectionsAtIndex` function that isn't called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working, Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3) In the doc: `optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets` which not the same as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem that insetForSectionAt is not called is that you have to implement it like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

   //access to minimumInteritemSpacing by casting to UICollectionViewFlowLayout
   let layout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
   let spacing = layout.minimumInteritemSpacing       

   return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.5,0,0.5,0)

}
```

Take a look on UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol. The insetForSectionAt is declared like this:

```
@available(iOS 6.0, *)
optional public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

So you need that first optional parameter, to implement this function.

Comment: XCode gave me a warning pointing to this function but it didn't do the job for me as it uses a `UICollectionViewLayout` rather than a `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. So the `collectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing` property doesn't exist.

Comment: now I saw your problem. you have to cast the collectionViewLayout correctly. I've updated my answer. This should work!

Comment: I suspect it will have, I've had technical issues with my computer so have been unable to try it. I'll update when I'm up and running again, thanks.

Comment: xcode throws errors saying to remove keyword 'optional'!?