# Swift not discovering any bluetooth devices

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

So I have written a (fairly) simple code to scan for Bluetooth devices, and connect to one with a matching name, but the function that is supposed to be called when a BT device is found is never being called. Could someone look this over and see if you can find an error in my work?

Things I have tried:

1. changing the service uuid in the scan initialization to nil to scan for all devices
2. Using NSLog statements to detect when the didDiscover program found a device
3. A bunch of breakpoints to break at the start of each function.

I am really confused by this, I followed a page called [The 12 Steps of Bluetooth](http://kevinhoyt.com/2016/05/20/the-12-steps-of-bluetooth-swift), and double checking with apple developer reference pages.

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth


class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    var manager:CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral:CBPeripheral!
    var peripherals = Array<CBPeripheral>()

    let devName = "CHS Bus Loop"
    let servUUID = CBUUID(string: "6e400001-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e")
    let txChar = CBUUID(string: "6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
    let rxChar = CBUUID(string: "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E")
    var txCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        textLabel.text="CHS We Are One"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        } else {
            print("Bluetooth not available.")
        }
    }



    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverperipheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
        let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary)
            .object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)
            as? NSString
        if device?.contains(devName) == true{
            self.manager.stopScan()

            self.peripheral = peripheral
            self.peripheral.delegate = self

            manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }

        func centralManager2(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectperipheral peripheral: CBPeripheral){
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        }
        func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral,didDiscoverServices error: NSError?){
            for service in peripheral.services! {
                let thisService = service as CBService

                if service.uuid == txChar{
                    peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for:thisService)
                }
            }
        }

        func peripheral(
            peripheral: CBPeripheral,
            didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService,
            error: NSError?) {
            for characteristic in service.characteristics! {
                let thisCharacteristic = characteristic as CBCharacteristic

                if thisCharacteristic.uuid == rxChar {
                    self.peripheral.setNotifyValue(
                        true, 
                        for: thisCharacteristic
                    )
                }
            }
        }




        peripherals.append(peripheral)
        //tableView.reloadData()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    //@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var deviceSelector: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField6: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var direct1: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var direct2: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var direct3: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var direct4: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var direct5: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var direct6: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func UpdateDecimal(_ sender: Any) {
        var LED1=""
        var LED2=""
        var LED3=""
        var LED4=""
        var LED5=""
        var LED6=""
        var combine=""

        if direct1.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            LED1 = "002"
        }else{
            LED1 = self.textField1.text! + "\(direct1.selectedSegmentIndex)"
        }

        if direct2.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            LED2 = "002"
        }else{
            LED2 = self.textField2.text! + "\(direct2.selectedSegmentIndex)"
        }

        if direct3.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            LED3 = "002"
        }else{
            LED3 = self.textField3.text! + "\(direct3.selectedSegmentIndex)"
        }

        if direct4.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            LED4 = "002"
        }else{
            LED4 = self.textField4.text! + "\(direct4.selectedSegmentIndex)"
        }

        if direct5.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            LED5 = "002"
        }else{
            LED5 = self.textField5.text! + "\(direct5.selectedSegmentIndex)"
        }

        if direct6.selectedSegmentIndex == 2{
            LED6 = "002"
        }else{
            LED6 = self.textField6.text! + "\(direct6.selectedSegmentIndex)"
        }

        if LED1.characters.count == 2{
            LED1="0" + LED1
        }
        if LED2.characters.count == 2{
            LED2="0" + LED2
        }
        if LED3.characters.count == 2 {
            LED3="0" + LED3
        }
        if LED4.characters.count == 2{
            LED4="0" + LED4
        }
        if LED5.characters.count == 2{
            LED5="0" + LED5
        }
        if LED6.characters.count == 2{
            LED6="0" + LED6
        }

        if LED1.characters.count + LED2.characters.count + LED3.characters.count + LED4.characters.count + LED5.characters.count + LED6.characters.count != 18{
            textLabel.text = "All MUST have 2 digits"
        }else{
            combine = LED1 + LED2 + LED3 + LED4 + LED5 + LED6
            textLabel.text = combine
        }
        let data = combine.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        peripheral.writeValue(data!, for: txCharacteristic!,
            type:CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse);


    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see you call scanForPeripherals after you initialize manager. If centralManagerDidUpdateState(_:) doesn't run, you will never scan for peripherals.

Comment: @Dare line 24. Its in func centralManagerDidUpdateState, it checks if state is poweredon, and if so, starts the scan.

Comment: So you never get a call to `didDiscoverPeripheral`? Have you tried the LightBlue app to see if it can see your peripheral? Checking the advertisement data for the peripheral name may not work, depending on your peripheral and the contents of the advertisement.

Comment: As Paulw11 said, check if you can see your device with LightBlue, if it's really a BLE device and can be found (if it advertises). But I guess that your issue lies between mixing Swift 3 and old Swift methods. Check there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3/40492091#40492091) for the answer to adapt to your needs.

Comment: @Larme I will look at that, my device is an adafruit BLE UART device. Is it possible you could tell me what looks outdated? I will look around for removing possible errors, but some pointers (not the c kind) might help me out.

Comment: Replace: `func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverperipheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)` => `func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)`. Read again my linked answer. Check all the real declaration of the delegate methods, especially yours which don't have a "_". And you can't have a `centralManager2()...` like yours, it won't work neither.

Comment: @Larme Thanks man, I will check these ASAP

Comment: @Larme that fixed it, but now the peripheral.writeValue line fails, I have it written as `peripheral.writeValue(_ data: Data, for txChar: CBCharacteristic, writeType: CBCharacteristicWriteType`, It throws errors about wanting an expression in list of expressions, a `,` seperator, and an overload failure match.

Comment: I don't use Swift, but I'd suggest this: write yourself "peripheral.writeV" and let XCode autocomplete.

Comment: @Larme can you put your comment that starts with the word "Replace" as an answer, it worked so I would like to mark it correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working, Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3) I marked the question as duplicate because the reason is the same (Swift 3 changes in its nomenclatures/rules), just need to be adapted to CoreBluetooth and your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following help from @Larme, I found that there were some swift2 functions and some swift3 functions, and they will not work together. here is his full commend:

> Replace: func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverperipheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) => func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber). Read again my linked answer. Check all the real declaration of the delegate methods, especially yours which don't have a "_". And you can't have a centralManager2()... like yours, it won't work neither.

If @Larme wishes to post the answer himself, I will make his correct, and remove mine.