# Swift 3, iOS10.3 - Email window opens, but doesn't close

Tags: ios, swift, email, window

I can open an email window in iOS 10.3 by pressing a button but I can't close it (cancel & send don't close it). As I'm new to Swift, I'm assuming there is an obvious mistake I don't see in my code  :)

```
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import Foundation

class settings: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func sendEmailButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        self.present(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
    }
}
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["email@email.com"])
    mailComposerVC.setSubject("Subject of email")
    return mailComposerVC
}
func showSendMailErrorAlert() {
    let sendMailErrorAlert = UIAlertView(title: "Could Not Send Email", message: "Your device could not send Email.  Please check Email configuration and try again.", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    sendMailErrorAlert.show()
}

func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: You are mixing Swift 2 and Swift 3 methods. For instance `func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController!, didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError!)` needs to be replace with `func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?)` See the Swift Type `NSError` vs `Error`, and the "_", and the less verbose parameters introductions: ` didFinishWith result:` vs `didFinishWithResult result:`. So your method won't be called because it's not the one expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working, Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3)