# Swift 3 - Bluetooth Low Energy didConnectPeripheral() is never called

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have seen this question a few times but nobody seems to have found a proper answer, so I will post again.

I am using **Swift 3** and Xcode to scan for **BLE peripherals**. I then add these to a table view if they have a certain name `('THX_BLE').`

Once clicked on, a connection is established.

Now this is the interesting part that I cannot seem to understand. According to several pieces of documentation, the function didConnectPeripheral() is meant to be called when a successful connection to a peripheral is established.

Now I am using a HM10 Bluetooth UART BLE module which has a little LED on it to tell you if you are connected or not. The light stops flashing and tells me I am connected.

*This module may be real or fake but either way that shouldn't matter, its function is the same.*

**So why isn't this method being called?** It is all in one class.

Thanks.

Here is the entire view code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

// Conform to CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate protocols

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    //MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var deviceTable: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var helpButton: UIButton!

    //MARK: Variables
    var centralManager:CBCentralManager!
    var sensorTag:CBPeripheral?

    var keepScanning = false
    let timerPauseInterval:TimeInterval = 10.0
    let timerScanInterval:TimeInterval = 2.0

    var peripherals = Array<CBPeripheral>()
    let cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 10

    let deviceName = " THX_BLE"

    //MARK: Functions

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 28/255.0, green: 34/255.0, blue: 60/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        deviceTable.alwaysBounceVertical = false

        searchButton.layer.cornerRadius=10
        searchButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        searchButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        searchButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)

        helpButton.layer.cornerRadius=10
        helpButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        helpButton.layer.borderWidth = 2
        helpButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 15, bottom: 15, right: 15)

        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return (peripherals.count)
    }

    // Set the spacing between sections
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellSpacingHeight
    }

    // Make the background color show through
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return headerView
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.layer.cornerRadius=20 //set corner radius here
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor  // set cell border color here
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 2 // set border width here

        let peripheral = peripherals[indexPath.row]
        cell.myLabel?.text = peripheral.name

        return (cell)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ViewControllerTableViewCell
        cell.myLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        deviceTable.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)
        cell.myLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        print("Forming connection with device")
        // Request a connection to the peripheral
        // save a reference to the sensor tag
        let peripheral = peripherals[indexPath.row]
        sensorTag = peripheral
        sensorTag!.delegate = self
        centralManager.connect(sensorTag!, options: nil)
        centralManager.stopScan()

//        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
//        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presetController") as! PresetViewController
//        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }

    // MARK: - CBCentralManagerDelegate methods

    // Invoked when the central manager’s state is updated.
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print("Did update state called")
        var showAlert = true
        var message = ""

        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOff:
            message = "Bluetooth on this device is currently powered off."
        case .unsupported:
            message = "This device does not support Bluetooth Low Energy."
        case .unauthorized:
            message = "This app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy."
        case .resetting:
            message = "The BLE Manager is resetting; a state update is pending."
        case .unknown:
            message = "The state of the BLE Manager is unknown."
        case .poweredOn:
            showAlert = false
            message = "Bluetooth LE is turned on and ready for communication."

            print(message)
            keepScanning = true
            _ = Timer(timeInterval: timerScanInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(pauseScan), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

            // Initiate Scan for Peripherals
            //Option 1: Scan for all devices
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

            // Option 2: Scan for devices that have the service you're interested in...
            //let sensorTagAdvertisingUUID = CBUUID(string: Device.SensorTagAdvertisingUUID)
            //print("Scanning for SensorTag adverstising with UUID: \(sensorTagAdvertisingUUID)")
            //centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices([sensorTagAdvertisingUUID], options: nil)

        }

        if showAlert {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Central Manager State", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.show(alertController, sender: self)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Bluetooth scanning

    @objc func pauseScan() {
        // Scanning uses up battery on phone, so pause the scan process for the designated interval.
        print("*** PAUSING SCAN...")
        _ = Timer(timeInterval: timerPauseInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(resumeScan), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
        centralManager.stopScan()
    }

    @objc func resumeScan() {
        if keepScanning {
            // Start scanning again...
            print("*** RESUMING SCAN!")
            _ = Timer(timeInterval: timerScanInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(pauseScan), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
            centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        } else {
        }
    }

    /*
     Invoked when the central manager discovers a peripheral while scanning.

     The advertisement data can be accessed through the keys listed in Advertisement Data Retrieval Keys.
     You must retain a local copy of the peripheral if any command is to be performed on it.
     In use cases where it makes sense for your app to automatically connect to a peripheral that is
     located within a certain range, you can use RSSI data to determine the proximity of a discovered
     peripheral device.

     central - The central manager providing the update.
     peripheral - The discovered peripheral.
     advertisementData - A dictionary containing any advertisement data.
     RSSI - The current received signal strength indicator (RSSI) of the peripheral, in decibels.

     */

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
//        print("centralManager didDiscoverPeripheral - CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey is \"\(CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey)\"")

        // Retrieve the peripheral name from the advertisement data using the "kCBAdvDataLocalName" key
        if let peripheralName = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey] as? String {
            print("NEXT PERIPHERAL NAME: \(peripheralName)")
            print("NEXT PERIPHERAL UUID: \(peripheral.identifier.uuidString)")

            if (peripheralName == deviceName) {
                print("SENSOR TAG FOUND! ADDING NOW!!!")
                // to save power, stop scanning for other devices
                peripherals.append(peripheral)
                deviceTable.reloadData()
                keepScanning = false
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     Invoked when a connection is successfully created with a peripheral.

     This method is invoked when a call to connectPeripheral:options: is successful.
     You typically implement this method to set the peripheral’s delegate and to discover its services.
     */
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print("**** SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED!!!")


        // Now that we've successfully connected to the SensorTag, let's discover the services.
        // - NOTE:  we pass nil here to request ALL services be discovered.
        //          If there was a subset of services we were interested in, we could pass the UUIDs here.
        //          Doing so saves battery life and saves time.
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    /*
     Invoked when you discover the peripheral’s available services.

     This method is invoked when your app calls the discoverServices: method.
     If the services of the peripheral are successfully discovered, you can access them
     through the peripheral’s services property.

     If successful, the error parameter is nil.
     If unsuccessful, the error parameter returns the cause of the failure.
     */
    // When the specified services are discovered, the peripheral calls the peripheral:didDiscoverServices: method of its delegate object.
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("ERROR DISCOVERING SERVICES: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        // Core Bluetooth creates an array of CBService objects —- one for each service that is discovered on the peripheral.
        if let services = peripheral.services {
            for service in services {
                print("Discovered service \(service)")
                // If we found either the temperature or the humidity service, discover the characteristics for those services.
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }
    }


    /*
     Invoked when the central manager fails to create a connection with a peripheral.

     This method is invoked when a connection initiated via the connectPeripheral:options: method fails to complete.
     Because connection attempts do not time out, a failed connection usually indicates a transient issue,
     in which case you may attempt to connect to the peripheral again.
     */
    private func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        print("**** CONNECTION TO SENSOR TAG FAILED!!!")
    }

    /*
     Invoked when an existing connection with a peripheral is torn down.

     This method is invoked when a peripheral connected via the connectPeripheral:options: method is disconnected.
     If the disconnection was not initiated by cancelPeripheralConnection:, the cause is detailed in error.
     After this method is called, no more methods are invoked on the peripheral device’s CBPeripheralDelegate object.

     Note that when a peripheral is disconnected, all of its services, characteristics, and characteristic descriptors are invalidated.
     */
    private func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {
        print("**** DISCONNECTED FROM SENSOR TAG!!!")
        if error != nil {
            print("****** DISCONNECTION DETAILS: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        sensorTag = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Same reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3/40492091#40492091
Your methods (didConnectPeripheral, didDiscoverServices , didDisconnectPeripheral, didFailToConnectPeripheral) are not Swift 3, check the doc to get the Swift 3 one, or just erase it and let the autocompletion do its job.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it.

Comment: Thanks. Silly of me. I have been referring to many pieces of documentation, one of them was Swift 2. I don't know if you want to submit that as an answer.

Comment: Don't worry, it's an easy mistake and one of the problems of Swift. You can mark yourself the question as a duplicate of the linked one, in order to people to see clearly the solution.