# Updating code to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am a beginner to programming with swift and programming in general. I am currently working on an app which allows one phone to send a message (peripheral) to another which will receive the message (central). I have taken most of the code from an app built using swift 2 and have tweaked it slightly to remove any errors. As a result, my code is a jumble of swift 2/3 (or so I have been told). I am not sure how to update this code fully to swift 3 which I need someones help to do. I believe it is the IBActions and delegates that are outdated but I am completely clueless on how to amend it.

I have tried running the app and it runs successfully but when I press any of the buttons nothing happens as far as I can tell. I have a basic understanding of what my code does and what each function is there for but I find myself stuck on what to do for it to work. If anyone has experience working with Bluetooth via swift and can see what I am doing wrong or perhaps if I haven't included something important. I am led to believe the issue is that all the code has not been updated to swift 3 but I can't be sure. I have read the Apple documentation for Core bluetooth.

PS: I know this question is very vague as I am unsure on what part of my code I need to fix so it is very difficult to make it specific to a single issue. Sorry!

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    let messageUUID = CBUUID(string: "053D6600-821E-46A7-AC25-43A81D948E8B")
    let inputUUID = CBUUID(string: "49A79D26-5323-4374-81EA-29B099AF85C8")
    let otherUUID = CBUUID(string: "053D6600-821E-46A7-AC25-43A81D948E87")
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!
    var characteritic: CBMutableCharacteristic!
    var getDataPeripheralCharacteristic: CBMutableCharacteristic!
    var service: CBMutableService!
    var outputData:String = ""
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var connectingPeripheral: CBPeripheral?
    var centralWriteCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic!


    @IBOutlet var inputLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


    @IBAction func centralMode(_ sender: UIButton) {
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        peripheralManager = nil
    }


    @IBAction func peripheralMode(_ sender: UIButton) {
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        centralManager = nil
    }




    @IBAction func sendData(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (peripheralManager != nil) {
            let passed = peripheralManager.updateValue(inputLabel.text!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, for: characteritic!, onSubscribedCentrals: nil)
            if passed == false {
                print("error couldn't send data")
            }
        }
        if (centralManager != nil) {
            if (connectingPeripheral != nil) {
                connectingPeripheral?.writeValue(inputLabel.text!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, for: centralWriteCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse)
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if (peripheral.state == .poweredOn) {
            characteritic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: messageUUID, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties.notify, value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.readable)
            getDataPeripheralCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: inputUUID, properties:
                CBCharacteristicProperties.write, value: nil, permissions: CBAttributePermissions.writeable)
            service = CBMutableService(type: otherUUID, primary: true)
            service.characteristics = [characteritic!, getDataPeripheralCharacteristic!]
            peripheralManager!.add(service)
        }
    }


    func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAddService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
            peripheral.stopAdvertising()
        let identifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
        let manufacturerData = identifier.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
        let dataToBeAdvertised:[String: Any] = [
            CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey : "Sample peripheral",
            CBAdvertisementDataManufacturerDataKey : manufacturerData as Any,
            CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey : [messageUUID, inputUUID],
            ]

        peripheralManager.startAdvertising(dataToBeAdvertised)
    }




    func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWriteRequests requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
        for request in requests {
            if (request.characteristic.uuid.uuidString == inputUUID.uuidString) {
                outputData = String(data: request.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                outputLabel.text = outputData
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveReadRequest request: CBATTRequest) {
    }

    func peripheralManager(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeToCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
        outputLabel.text = "Press send message"
        print("Now connected")
    }


        func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
            if central.state == .poweredOn {
                centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
                //search for peripheral device
            }
        }


        //when peripheral is discovered, this method is called

        private func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
            self.centralManager.stopScan();
            self.connectingPeripheral = peripheral;
            peripheral.delegate = self;
            centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }

        //if connection request from central is succesfull, this method is called
        func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
            peripheral.delegate = self;
            peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        }

        //if central discovers services, this method is called
        private func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {
            for service: CBService in peripheral.services! {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }

        private func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {
            if (service.uuid.uuidString == otherUUID.uuidString) {
                guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else {
                    return
                }
                for characteristic in characteristics {
                    if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == messageUUID.uuidString {
                        peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
                } else if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == inputUUID.uuidString {
                    centralWriteCharacteristic = characteristic
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    private func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error reading characteristics");
        }
        if (characteristic.uuid == messageUUID) {
            outputData = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
            print(outputData)
            outputLabel.text = outputData
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: I have also tried following this tutorial (https://itnext.io/whos-there-simple-swift-app-for-chatting-with-colleagues-around-a88ff765736f) as it was created recently but there are some features I simply do not want e.g. the registration screen. I have been unsuccessful in taking out this feature without the rest of the app not being able to work. If someone knows how to do this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why have you made some  functions private , I think you should remove private keyword and then try running the app again

Comment: You can check there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3/40492091#40492091 to find which ones to update for "iOS SDK ones".

Comment: I have made them private to silence a warning. It comes up with the warning message that it nearly matches optional requirement of protocol from CBPeripheralDelegate and CBCentralDelegate

Comment: To recognize the ones that have to be changed: If they don't have a `_` before their first parameter they may have to be changed. If they are verbose as Objective-C : `myIntroductionToParameterWithParameterName myParameterName: parameterTypeOrClass` instead of `myIntroductionToParameter myParameterName: parameterTypeOrClass` they have to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue is because of swift 2/3 mismatch. Try upgrading your code to swift3.

1. Go to Xcode-edit-convert- to current swift syntax.
2. This will lead to few build errors, identify them and fix them.
3. Make your sure if you have any pod or cart file , do not forget to upgrade them as well.

Hopefully this should resolve your issue.