# Collection view cell border color Deselect in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview

Use this code to select or deselect the border color of collection view cell but it select the border color but not deselect the border color.
i used so many code but it didn't worked.please share the info

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){

Image2.image = UIImage(named: Images[indexPath.row])

let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2
cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
//        selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
}

  private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {

let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2
cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

}
```

Comment: your `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` function is `private`?

Comment: `private func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)` That method shouldn't be called because it's not the Swift 3 version of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working, Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491818/didselectrowatindexpath-not-working-swift-3)

Comment: Thanks Piyush Patel it worked ,i used wrong method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) { 
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DateCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
}
func collectionView(_collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DateCell

    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
}

Try This One
```

Answer (score 2):

I used your code it's working good but just remove `private` keyword at started from `didDeselectItemAt` method like

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,yes i did and its working